# What is a convention for indicating the intended flavor of a Markdown script?

Tags: markdown, conventions, doctype

There seem to be a lot of flavors of Markdown. What are any conventions for indicating the target flavor within a Markdown script? Perhaps something similar to:

```
<!DOCTYPE Markdown "Jupyter Notebooks">
```

Comment: None exists, as far as I know. There isn't even a universal "comment" or metadata format for Markdown—many flavours support YAML preambles, but that certainly wasn't part of the original spec. You could provide such information in an accompanying file, like a README.

Comment: Might be a good idea to https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark-spec/issues/new.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such convention. But typically no such information is needed, because Markdown is not an end user format. It isn't meant for communicating information directly. It is meant for transformation into HTML and from there to rendering in a browser. And that will happen in a specific context, which you control or know.

For example, GitHub flavored Markdown is for making web pages on GitHub; if you're writing a GitHub ReadMe you know that and you obey those conventions.

And I make my own web site's pages using [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org), but no one knows that or needs to know it, because what they see is the rendered pages in a browser.

Comment: Right. But tomorrow I might start using "slamdown," the next day "shutdown," then "slowdown." And I might want to make a note of which one was assumed for which Markdown file, because I might "forgetdown." I suppose if these are my private files, I can put human readable comment near the top of the file `<!-- REMINDER: this Markdown script is intended for rendering by kramdown.-->`.

Comment: Only if this is the kind of Markdown that allows HTML-style comments. Many kinds do not.

Comment: And while you're exercising your sarcasm muscles, do note that kramdown is a real Markdown flavor — in my opinion, the _best_ Markdown flavor.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't intending sarcasm, just not being very creative with naming things.